# Properly remove StyleCop R# plugin

Tags: c#, resharper, stylecop

I installed StyleCop and the associated plugin for ReSharper 5.  After getting annoyed with it I removed both the plugin and StyleCop, but ReSharper is still using some of the StyleCop behaviour - most notably moving `using` statements to within the namespace declaration, rather than keeping them outside the declaration.

For instance say you have the following source:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace Foo.Bar
{
    ////
}
```

And the file sits within The `Foo/Bar/Widget` directory, using ReSharper's fix namespace tool I would expect the file to stay the same, but the namespace to have changed to `Foo.Bar.Widgets` (this is the behaviour it exhibited before StyleCop came along).

Now however it rearranges the file:

```
namespace Foo.Bar.Widget
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    ////
}
```

Now putting aside people's personal preferences about which one is better, I don't like it, and it is inconsistent with our existing code.  Having to manually move using statements after renaming the namespace takes long than renaming the namespace manually.

Does anyone know how to correct this (I'm assuming there is a file or something still lingering around from the install, or a config that hasn't been reverted).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change it here:

*ReSharper -> Options -> Languages -> C# -> Namespace Imports -> Add using directive to the deepest scope*

**UPDATE - Resharper 9** This option is now moved to:

*ReSharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Code Style -> Reference qualification*

Comment: You're a champ.  Strange though - I don't recall ever changing that setting and for as long as I can remember, using R# didn't do it that way.  Either way, un-ticking it fixed the problem.  Cheers.

Comment: ReSharper had never this default. StyleCop plugin changes this settings, and haven/t reverted it back after uninstall

Comment: @Evgeny, I edited the answer to remove the incorrect statement about R#'s default behaviour.

Answer (score 10):

I just had the same issue. It turns out that the StyleCop settings are stored in the "This computer" layer of ReSharper settings. See *ReSharper > Manage Options* for a list of layers.

I just had to reset the "This computer" layer; this was possible since I had never intentionally modified it.